# How can I test/validate the header hierarchy of a section in cypress?

Tags: html, jquery, unit-testing, testing, cypress

i want to enforce the structure that headers follow a hierarchy. Meaning if you go from bottom to top of the dom, thr next heading must be <= current or + 1.

Here is the console log of my headings in one of my sections for example:

```
Yielded:

0: h2.mt-4
1: h3.mt-16.text-base.w-64
2: h4.mt-0.font-normal.text-sm
3: h4.mt-0.font-normal.text-sm
4: h4.mt-0.font-normal.text-sm
5: h3.mt-16.text-base.w-64
6: h4.mt-0.font-normal.text-sm
7: h4.mt-0.font-normal.text-sm
8: h4.mt-0.font-normal.text-sm
9: h4.mt-0.font-normal.text-sm
10: h3.mt-16.text-base.w-64
11: h4.mt-0.font-normal.text-sm
12: h4.mt-0.font-normal.text-sm
```

This would be valid ^

```
Yielded:   

0: h2.mt-4
1: h3.mt-16.text-base.w-64
2: h4.mt-0.font-normal.text-sm
3: h4.mt-0.font-normal.text-sm
4: h4.mt-0.font-normal.text-sm
5: h3.mt-16.text-base.w-64
6: h4.mt-0.font-normal.text-sm
7: h4.mt-0.font-normal.text-sm
8: h4.mt-0.font-normal.text-sm
9: h4.mt-0.font-normal.text-sm
10: h3.mt-16.text-base.w-64
11: h1.mt-0.font-normal.text-sm
12: h1.mt-0.font-normal.text-sm
```

And this is not ^^^

So far I can loop through the sections and get each sections headers, but a bit stumped on how to loop through and force that rule. It would require comparing the current header and the next one in the array.

What I have so far:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("checkHeadingHeirarchy", () => {
  cy.get("section").each(($section) => {
    cy.get($section).within(() => {
      cy.get("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6"); //now what?...
    });
  });
});
```

@agoff: The `console.log` shows us the first $el and then the $list[index + 1]:

```
This is the $el: jQuery.fn.init [h2.mt-4]
This is the $el: <h3 data-cy=​"header" class=​"mt-16 text-base w-64">​Engineering​</h3>​
```

@agoff: This works, but its hacky:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("checkHeadingHeirarchy", () => {
  cy.get("section").each(($section) => {
    cy.get($section).within(() => {
      cy.get("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6").each(($el, index, $list) => {
        // Don't run the validation on the last item in the list
        if (index !== $list.length - 1) {
          // Get the size of the current and next header
          const currSize = getHeaderNumber($el);
          const nextSize = getHeaderNumber($list, index + 1);
          try {
            expect(currSize <= nextSize || currSize + 1 === nextSize).to.eql(
              true
            );
          } catch {
            console.log("Failed on current size:", currSize);
            console.log("Failed on next size:", nextSize);
            throw error;
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
});

// helper function to get header number
const getHeaderNumber = ($el, index) => {
  console.log("Going to parse this:", $el.get(index ?? 0));
  try {
    console.log("Got this:", parseInt($el.get(index ?? 0).tagName.slice(1)));
    return parseInt($el.get(index ?? 0).tagName.slice(1));
  } catch {
    console.log("ERROR ON:", $el.get(index ?? 0));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can yield the index of the elements yielded, as well as the entire list. Using that, we can easily compare the next yielded item.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("checkHeadingHeirarchy", () => {
  cy.get("section").each(($section) => {
    cy.wrap($section).within(($sectionWithin) => {
      cy.get("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6").each(($el, index, $list) => {
        // Don't run the validation on the last item in the list
        if (index !== $list.length - 1) {
          // Get the size of the current and next header
          const currSize = getHeaderNumber($el)
          const nextSize = getHeaderNumber($list[index + 1])
          expect(currSize <= nextSize || currSize + 1 === nextSize).to.eql(true);
        }
      });
    });
  });
});

// helper function to get header number
const getHeaderNumber = ($el) => {
  const tagName = $el.prop('tagName') ?? $el.get(0).tagName
  return parseInt(tagName.slice(1), 10);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the reply, this looks like it will work. I am getting a small error from the `getHeaderNumber` function saying "`.get()` is not a function."

I've moved the parseInt into the main command and it seems to be erroring on `$list[(index + 1)].get is not a function`. Is it perhaps trying to run it on an empty $el?

Comment: So I can see that sometimes the `$el` is this, for example: `jQuery.fn.init [h2.mt-4]` and sometimes it is `<h3 data-cy="header" class="mt-16 text-base w-64">Engineering</h3>`

This is when I `console.log` the `$el` @agoff

Comment: Hmm... I was working off an assumption that would work. If you sub out the `$el.get(0).tagName.slice(1)` for `$el.prop('tagName')`, does it work as expected? I didn't have an exactly reproducible website to test this out on. I can try to whip something up real quick.

Comment: It seems that sometimes the $el is an array, therefore the `.get(0)` works, then sometimes its just a single element for some reason

Unfortunately the `.prop` returns `NaN`

Comment: Hmmmm curious. I did some light testing on my own end and the `$el.prop()` worked as expected. I'm not sure why $el would be an array, the `.each()` function should yield a single element each time...

Comment: Can you `cy.log()` each `$el`, and post an example of one time it is an array vs. a single element?

Comment: Oh, already seeing one potential issue in using `.within()`. Going to update that and the `.prop()` part.

Comment: so it seems that the first one (where we say `getHeaderNumber($el)`, $el always returns an array with a length of 1. However, when we use `getHeaderNumber($list[index + 1])`, the `$list[index + 1]` gives us just the element by itself, not in an array. Will attach a console log.

Comment: hi agoff, ive added a method that works. I just work around the fact that sometimes we have an array and sometimes just a single element by passing in the `$list` and grabbing the element from inside there.

Comment: Hmm ok. I'll add a solution that might be a little better than what you've added in a bit. I'm not getting that list like you are, so won't be able to fully test it